# How can I add a file to a classpath but not to a jar with maven?

Tags: java, jar, maven, classpath, maven-jar-plugin

I want to add some configs to the classpath (generated by maven-jar-plugin), but I don't want them inside a jar, but in an external folder.  That way I'll be able to edit configs without repackaging.
I found one solution [How to add a classpath entry when executing the app with exec plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724290/how-to-add-a-classpath-entry-when-executing-the-app-with-exec-plugin) but is there a less complicated solution?

Or maybe I'm wrong and it's a bad pattern - storing configs in the classpath but outside a Jar? Maybe it's better to store app configs in the user's home directory and add them to the app at runtime?

For example I want to allow the end user to edit log4j.properties and translations.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest having a default location that it looks for the app configs (e.g. user home directory, as you suggested), but allow the user to provide an agrument/System property to override this location. Assuming to look on the classpath is not, in my opinion, the best solution, since the concept of a classpath is a fairly alien thing to most users, and can even be hard to determine for some programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Melv are right - better to store configs in Home directory and provide ability to change it, but if someone need add something to classpath - you just can add following code into `<configuration><archive>`.

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Class-Path>config/</Class-Path>
    <mode>development</mode>
    <url>${pom.url}</url>
</manifestEntries>
```

If you declare `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`, then dependency classpaths also will be added.